# Mad Scientist Interaction with duplicate secrets

Tags: hearthstone

Normally you can't play 2 of the same secrets at once.

However, let's say you have freezing trap already in play, and your deck still has 1 more freezing trap and no other secrets. If your mad scientists dies and triggers the deathrattle, would it cast the additional secret or just do nothing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*"If the only Secret left in your deck is a copy of one you already have active, Mad Scientist will draw nothing at all."*
-- [Ben Brode](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/491287156607160321), senior game designer on Hearthstone.

Comment: Related: Kezan Mystic cannot give you a duplicate secret as well, as demonstrated by this Hearthstone Mythbusters video: https://youtu.be/d34VAYF03ZE?t=52s

Comment: Huh.  I thought it drew the secret out of the deck and overwrote the current secret, thus wasting the one in the deck.